# Why does my Python program return "ValueError: math domain error"?

Tags: python, math, valueerror, square-root, pythagorean

I am making this very simple program which calculates the distance between the coordinates of a player and the coordinates of another place (for Minecraft).

```
import math
px = int(input("Your x-coordinate: "))
pz = int(input("Your z-coordinate: "))
x = int(input("X-coordinate of destination: "))
z = int(input("z-coordinate of destination: "))
dist = math.sqrt((px-x)^2+(pz-z)^2)
print("Distance is %d meters." % dist)
```

When I enter (0, 0) as my coordinates and (1, 1) as the other place's coordinates, Python returns "ValueError: math domain error" instead of the expected value of root 2. Though when I enter (0, 0) as both my coordinates AND the other place's coordinates, Python returns "0". Can someone please identify the issue for me and a possible solution?

Comment: `^` is XOR. Use `math.pow` or `**` for power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
dist = math.sqrt((px-x)^2+(pz-z)^2)
```

The [`^` symbol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) is used for the bitwise [XOR operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). For taking power, you should use either [`math.pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.pow) or `**`, i.e.,

```
dist = math.sqrt((px-x)**2+(pz-z)**2)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.hypot):

```
dist = math.hypot(px-x, pz-z)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GoodDeeds! I appreciate it. I haven't done any Python programming in months and I make these kinds of stupid mistakes.